# sort substrings list based on their position in a string

Tags: python, list, substring, inline

a would like to sort a list of substring (in one line preferably), like `['black red', 'matt black']`

based on their position in a string, like `'Example text matt black red etc'`

The result should be `['matt black', 'black red']`, just because `'matt black'` comes before in the string. How can i do in a single line?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to do it in more than a single line?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the index of the substring in the text as sorting key:

```
data = ['black red', 'matt black']
text = 'Example text matt black red etc'
out = list(sorted(data, key=lambda item: text.index(item)))

print(out)
# ['matt black', 'black red']
```

Note that if one of the substrings can't be found in the text, you'll get a `ValueError: substring not found` exception.

Comment: Note that this code can be simplified two-fold: 1)  `sorted` itself returns `list`, calling `list` function is not necessary, 2) `text.index` could be used directly - i.e. providing `key=text.index` has same effect as `key=lambda item: text.index(item)`